# Knockout/JS Referencing Observable In Other Function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just getting back in to the swing of things and seem to be losing my mind...

I have a function (model):

```
function Users(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.UserComments = ko.observableArray();
   //...some other thingies
}
```

And then...

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    //How do I access self.UserComments from the Users function?
}
```

Bonus points, question is somewhere in the comments. :)

Cheers

Edit:

To make it clearer I actually need the `self.UserComments` array (with data intact) accessible in my `viewModel`.

The `Users` function will add a comment to the `self.UserComments` array each time `data` is added in the `viewModel`,

Comment: What's the relationship to `Users` from your `viewModel`?

Comment: only way to do this by creating instance of `users` function i.e in VM `self.data=ko.observable(new users([//your data])` . you can access `userComments` via `self.data` . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to put one in your viewModel.

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.users = new Users({bla: 1});
    // Now I can reference it.
    self.count = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.users.UserComments().length;
    });
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion, however my `self.UserComments` array now has no data...I could be completely misinterpreting the way this should function.

Comment: It doesn't need to have data now.  you're defining subscriptions and flows.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.UserComments = ko.observableArray();
}
```